# How to silent the login.sql output

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-19c

```
[nir@dba etl]$ cat login.sql
col TAB# new_value TAB NOPRINT
select chr(9) TAB# from dual;
set markup csv on delimiter "&TAB" quote off
set heading off termout off echo off feedback off verify off numformat 99999999999.9999999999999 null '\N'
[nir@dba etl]$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

export ORACLE_PATH="/home/nir/etl"

echo "select * from dms_u.test_etl_source;" | sqlplus -s ${USER}/${PASS}@${TNS}

[nir@dba etl]$ ./a.sh




aa  \N  aa
\N  aa  aa
aa  aa  \N
\N  \N  aa
\N  aa  \N
aa  \N  \N
\N  \N  \N
aa  aa  aa
```

I'm using the `login.sql` to make the `sqlplus` output as tsv. What I want is to run `login.sql` without any output. If I would put it in `glogin.sql` the `-s` would work. But I need the tsv login to happen only on specific cases (therefore the `ORACLE_PATH`).

So I would want `a.sh` to return:

```
[nir@dba etl]$ ./a.sh
aa  \N  aa
\N  aa  aa
aa  aa  \N
\N  \N  aa
\N  aa  \N
aa  \N  \N
\N  \N  \N
aa  aa  aa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `login.sql` from:

```
col TAB# new_value TAB NOPRINT
select chr(9) TAB# from dual;
set markup csv on delimiter "&TAB" quote off
set heading off termout off echo off feedback off verify off numformat 99999999999.9999999999999 null '\N'
```

to:

```
set heading off termout off echo off feedback off verify off numformat 99999999999.9999999999999 null '\N'
col TAB# new_value TAB NOPRINT
select chr(9) TAB# from dual;
set markup csv on delimiter "&TAB" quote off
```